# Is there going to be a way to get ubuntu TV on a normal TV?

Tags: ubuntu-tv

Will there be a way to get all the features of an Ubuntu TV onto a regular TV by hooking up a computer to your TV?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be done. But it is not recommended for productive Systems.
You can find a complete how-to including a Ubuntu-ppa on this site:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-from-ppa.html

Alternatively you can compile it on your own. Instructions for everything can be found in the link.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is already possible to [install a development version of Ubuntu TV](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-right-now-via-ppa/) on a vanilla Ubuntu, so I think the answer is "yes".

Comment: I hear somewhere that ubuntu would work with your tv provider. Is it going to be able to make the computer control the actual tv you get from your provider?

Comment: Ubuntu TV is in a very early stage, what you saw in CES is what it is now, features will be added down the road, for now this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that like GoogleTV it will be available on a box as well as TV, but for a definitive answer you would have to wait until it is officially released.